# Why is the directory layout of Diamondback different when compiling from source?

Tags: ros, archlinux, rosinstall, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS Diamondback from source, following the guidelines here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Arch. Now, for Ubuntu installations I created a rosinstall
file that contains (besides other stuff) the following entries

```
other: { local-name: /opt/ros/diamondback/ros }
other: { local-name: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks }
```

When compiling from source (Desktop-Full) on archlinux, there is no *stacks* directory. When installing Diamondback via aptitude on Ubuntu, there is a *stacks* directory. This is both puzzling because I expect the final result of compilation from source to be the same as when installed with some package manager. Also, this breaks the rosinstall file.

Why is the layout different? (maybe also: how to fix the rosinstall file?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10936/why-is-the-directory-layout-of-diamondback-different-when-compiling-from-source?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Source trees and binaries installations frequently vary in layout for various reasons.  rosinstall is designed to give you a developer tree, whereas the binary installations are meant to be closer to a legal 'install' layout and support shared usage.  Different use cases result in differing layouts.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-09-03**:
The exact layout does not need to be the same as long as your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is set appropriately to find the packages you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The install instructions for Arch linux show how to get a user-local installation of ros in the directory ~/ros with all stacks being direct subdirectories of it.

If you have several users on the same computer, you might want to consider doing a shared installation with the same directory layout as the debian packages. Unfortunately there is no tutorial on this anymore. In short, you need to download the rosinstall file of the variant you want to use, adjust it to have all stacks in the subdir stacks and execute the rosinstall command (as root) with destination /opt/ros/. Then, again as root, execute

```
rosmake -a -i --rosdep-install
```

to build all packages and mark them as compiled in order to make them usable for users.

If you have only one user, you can use the arch installation and just add your stacks. Change your own rosinstall file to not contain the two lines you mentioned in your question and do:

```
rosinstall ~/ros your-file.rosinstall
```

This is basically the solution you pointed out already.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1